# Fullcalendar v4 ajax Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar

No puedo utilizar FullCalendar v4. En consola aparece el siguiente mensaje 
plugin file not loaded for interaction
plugin file not loaded for dayGrid
Uncaught Error: No available FullCalendar view plugins.

Hice el siguiente proceso:

instale los paquetes con npm.

```
npm install --save @fullcalendar/core @fullcalendar/interaction @fullcalendar/daygrid
```

luego compile los archivos.

```
npm run watch

Asset      Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/css/app.css   729 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
  /js/app.js  2.99 MiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app




    window.FullCalendar = require('@fullcalendar/core');
    window.interaction = require('@fullcalendar/interaction');
    window.dayGrid = require('@fullcalendar/daygrid');

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid' ],
      });

      calendar.render();
    });
    <div class="text-center" id='calendar'></div>
```

Gracias por su Colaboración.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás pasando el listado de plugins como strings. Eso solo es válido cuando importás los plugins mediante `<script>` ([documentación](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals)).

Cito:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ] // an array of strings!
});
```

> Keep in mind, this technique will not work if you are using an [ES6 build system](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6)!

---

En tu caso tenés que pasar una referencia a la importación de los plugins. No tengo mucha experiencia con el tema, así que no se como es con `require`, pero en la documentación figura con `import`:

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin],
    });

    calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: Utilice el código que mencionaste en app.js y funciono muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Intento 1: Traté de agregar el src JS en boostrap.js, agregando después de:

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

lo siguiente:

```
window.FullCalendar = require('@fullcalendar/core');
window.dayGrid = require('@fullcalendar/daygrid');
```

Luego "npm run dev"

Luego en la vista la llamada a fullcalendar:

index.blade.php

```
if(jQuery('#calendar1').length){
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar1');

        var calendar1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
           plugins: [ 'timeGrid', 'dayGrid', 'list' ],
           timeZone: 'UTC',
           defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
           header: {
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
           },
        .....
```

PERO... funciona la llamada a FullCalendar.Calendar pero nunca encuentra los plugins.

Intento 2:
Información de : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6

La única forma de que funcione es agregando todo el código en el archivo app.js, asi:

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('calendar').length) {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementsByClassName('calendar')[0];
        var calendar1 = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [ dayGridPlugin ]
        });
        calendar1.render();
    }
 });
```

Y luego correr npm run dev.

Comment: Mas info acá: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6